# Equation of angle bisector of two 3D straight lines

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems, angle

Just like we have it in 2D coordinate geometry, is there an equation which describes the angle bisector of two straight lines in  3D coordinate geometry?

Comment: What equations are you starting with? There are many ways to express a straight line in 3D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let direction vectors of lines be $\vec{l_1}$ and $\vec{l_2}$. And let the position vector of point of intersection of these lines be $\vec{p}$.

**Note** that if we add and subtract *equi-modular vectors which are in direction of $\vec{l_1}$ and $\vec{l_2}$*, we will obtain direction vectors of angular bisectors (You can show this by $RHS$ congruency of triangles). Here I considered unimodular vectors $\hat{l_1}$ and $\hat{l_2}$

The direction vectors of angular bisectors can be written as $\vec{b_1} =\hat{l_1} + \hat{l_2}$ and $\vec{b_2} = \hat{l_1} - \hat{l_2}$

So the angular bisector lines will be

$$\vec{r} = \vec{p} + k \vec{b_1}\\
\vec{r} = \vec{p} + k\vec{b_2}$$

Comment: Samjoe. Shouldn't you normalize l_1,l_2, and then! add or subtract to get bisectors?

Comment: @Peter What does normalize mean? I meant unit vectors $\hat{l_1}$, a vector which is unimodular and is in direction of $\vec{l}$

Comment: You might have mentioned in your answer that these were unit vectors in the first place. There’s no hard requirement that “direction vectors” be unimodular, hence the OP’s confusion.

Comment: @amd Yes but they need to be of same modulus, that is $\vec{l_1}$ and $\vec{l_2}$, so that their sum/difference is along angular bisectors.

Comment: Of course they do, eventually. That’s generally handled either by normalizing the vectors or, equivalently, by cross-multiplying by their norms, which is clearly what the OP was expecting to see.

Comment: Samjoe. l1, l2, your direction vectors. When  adding 2 vectors of the same length you get the angle bisector vector. If the two are of different length, this does not work. So ,if you have two different length vectors, divide each by its length, I.e. normalize, to get vectors of unit length. A drawing helps to visualize.Does this make sense? Peter

Comment: @Peter  I had already written $\hat{l_1}$. Do you know $\hat{l_1} = \frac{\vec{l_1}}{|\vec{l_1}|}$. When did I add vectors of different length :)

Comment: Samjoe.All is well.:))

Comment: @jonsno How do we check which of the following is acute angle bisector among $\vec{b_1}$ or $\vec{b_2}$